# Documentation of Java Mail API configuration for JNDI in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, jakarta-mail

I spend several days to figure out how to configure an javax.mail.Session in Tomcat via JNDI **with authentication**, now I get it but only after a deep dive in the code.

*In this time I have seen the worst code ever: javax.mail.Service#connect(String,String,String,String) Version 1.4.1*

```
    if (user == null) {
    user = url.getUsername();
    if (password == null)   // get password too if we need it
        password = url.getPassword();
    } else {
    if (password == null && user.equals(url.getUsername()))
        // only get the password if it matches the username
        password = url.getPassword();
    }
```

*When is the password assigned? and why is it checked against null twice? – and then realize that the else does not belong to the if above. (This is the original indentation). Back to topic.*

At least I found that the correct resource definition is:

```
<Resource name="email/session"
    type="javax.mail.Session"
    auth="Container"
    password="secret"

    mail.debug="false"
    mail.transport.protocol="smtp"

    mail.smtp.auth="true"
    mail.smtp.user="testi"
    mail.smtp.host="smtp.xxx.org"
    mail.smtp.from="test@example.com"       
    />
```

Pay attention to the fact that it is „password“ and „mail.smtp.user“ or „mail.user“ but not „mail.smtp.password“ or “user”.

At least the magic is done in Tomcats `org.apache.naming.factory.MailSessionFactory`. This factory add an `javax.mail.Authenticator` to the mail session if an property `password` and an property `mail.smtp.user` or `mail.user` exits.

**Now my question is where is the documentation for all that stuff. Especially about configuration of username and password?**

*Btw: I explained it a bit more detailed to help other how has the same problem.*

Comment: There is an issue reported in August 2012 for this at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53665

Comment: I would say the final 'else' should have been removed. Mostly this kind of thing is due to code evolution over long periods of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat documentation is limited but the source code is here: http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/tomcat/tomcat-7.0.19/org/apache/naming/factory/MailSessionFactory.java.html

Comment: Yes, I know. I my question I already pointed out which classes the magic do. -- But I will accept the answer because of the first part ("Tomcat documentation is limited") -- It seams to be the only right answer.

Comment: FYI the Tomcat docs have been updated. The changes will be in 7.0.42 onwards: http://svn.apache.org/r1495016

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a bug in the documentation.  Someone has already raised this on the Tomcat bug tracker

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53665

I suggest you register and vote for the bug.