# Logback SMTPAppender: Where/how to specify to/from field when using JNDI

Tags: java, jndi, logback, smtpappender

**Edit**: All I'm *really* asking here is: *how do you specify `to` and `from` email addresses with Logback's `SMTPAppender` when it's configured to use JNDI lookups?* This should be a basic form of functionality for the `SMTPAppender` and there'd be no way for `SMTPAppender` to work with JNDI lookups if it doesn't support this functionality!

I have the following Logback `SMTPAppender` defined:

```
<appender name="logManager-smtpAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>NEUTRAL</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>

    <asynchronousSending>false</asynchronousSending>

    <sessionViaJNDI>true</sessionViaJNDI>
    <jndiLocation>java:comp/env/mail/Session-local</jndiLocation>

    <subject>%logger{20} - %m</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
    <cyclicBufferTracker class="ch.qos.logback.core.spi.CyclicBufferTracker">
        <bufferSize>25</bufferSize>
    </cyclicBufferTracker>
</appender>
```

As you see, I'm using JNDI to lookup mail server credentials.

When this runs, I get:

> 15:50:06,857 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender[logManager-smtpAppender] - Empty destination address. Aborting email transmission

This made me realize: no where in the `SMTPAppender` above, or in my `context.xml` am I specifying the to/from email addresses.

**How/where (examples, please!) do I specify these?!?** I checked Logback's source code and this message gets printed from inside `SMTPAppenderBase.java`:

```
List<InternetAddress> destinationAddresses = parseAddress(lastEventObject);
if (destinationAddresses.isEmpty()) {
    addInfo("Empty destination address. Aborting email transmission");
    return;
}

private List<InternetAddress> parseAddress(E event) {
    int len = toPatternLayoutList.size();

    List<InternetAddress> iaList = new ArrayList<InternetAddress>();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        try {
            PatternLayoutBase<E> emailPL = toPatternLayoutList.get(i);
            String emailAdrr = emailPL.doLayout(event);
            if (emailAdrr == null || emailAdrr.length() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            InternetAddress[] tmp = InternetAddress.parse(emailAdrr, true);
            iaList.addAll(Arrays.asList(tmp));
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            addError("Could not parse email address for [" +         toPatternLayoutList.get(i) + "] for event [" + event + "]", e);
            return iaList;
        }
    }
    return iaList;
}
```

But I still can't tell where/how I'm supposed to set to/from fields. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. SMTPAppender cannot use JNDI as a connection source and successfully send emails as of 1.0.13 (it was prematurely released).

Answer (score 4):

The to and from addresses aren't related to the javamail [Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Session.html).  The javamail Session is used to configure how a message is transported, not the details of an individual message.

You set the to and from fields in the xml config with lines as shown in the [example](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html),

```
<configuration>   
  <appender name="EMAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <smtpHost>ADDRESS-OF-YOUR-SMTP-HOST</smtpHost>
    <to>EMAIL-DESTINATION</to>
    <to>ANOTHER_EMAIL_DESTINATION</to> <!-- additional destinations are possible -->
    <from>SENDER-EMAIL</from>
    <subject>TESTING: %logger{20} - %m</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%date %-5level %logger{35} - %message%n</pattern>
    </layout>       
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="EMAIL" />
  </root>  
</configuration>
```

> get the SMTPAppender working with the mail session credentials defined inside a JNDI connection source

Setting up the java mail session credentials in jndi is specific to the application server you are using.  For example you can configure jndi credentials for tomcat as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372171/documentation-of-java-mail-api-configuration-for-jndi-in-tomcat).  For weblogic you configure it like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/mail/CreateMailSessions.html).

Comment: Thanks @sbridges (+1), but I get the same exact "error message" (*Empty destination address. Aborting email transmission*) even when I define `<to>` and `<from>`...Also I am deploying to Tomcat, and defining the JNDI connection sources in Tomcat's global `conf/context.xml`. file.

Comment: Perhaps you can get SMTPAppender working where you specify all the Mail session credentials in `context.xml`, but the to/from addresses in logback.xml?

Comment: You are defining the to and from in logback.xml, and the credentials in context.xml, and that doesn't work?

Comment: Correct @sbridges - to/from in logback.xml and credentials in context.xml, and getting "Empty destination address. Aborting email transmission."

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in parseAddress(), is toPatternLayoutList empty?  What are the values in it?

Comment: Thanks again @sbridges - yes, toPatternLayoutList is empty, and therefore the "len" variable has a size of 0 and that entire for-loop doesn't even execute.

Comment: Rather than debugging this line-by-line, it may be quicker for you to get a working implementation and post the exact code; that way I can copy and paste. If your code works and my code doesn't, then we know its something else (system issues, environment issue, Tomcat issues, etc.) and not a bug with SMTPAppender!

Comment: The example in my answer is straight from the docs and should work.  I think you need to debug on your side, I suspect it is not reading the logback config file you are editing.

Comment: Thanks again @sbridges but the example you gave does **not** use JNDI to define the mail session (specifically, using the `sessionViaJndi` and `jndiLocation` elements). So it is **not** the same set up as what I'm describing here. I'm asking for someone to help me get SMTPAppender working **with JNDI** defining the Mail session. The logback book (which I have read most of) and your example above, are for using SMTPAppender **without JNDI**, which is *not* what I'm asking here! Thanks again for all your help so far!

Comment: Also, I haven't posted other console output just to keep my question as compact as possible, but I **do** see output that acknowledges it has found my `logback.xml` on the classpath and is reading configurations from it.